# making a piggy bank program in python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python and programming, and I'm trying to make a simple piggy bank that will be able to deposit or withdraw pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters. I don't know how to loop the code or how to store the data if I enter a coin to be able to keep adding to the total number of coins in the bank. I can only do it so it runs and tells me if I add, for example, 100 pennies, that my bank has 100 pennies. but then it resets. How do I do this? my code is probably awful but here's what I have so far based off my current knowledge of python (added empty parts like the "return" and pennies_previous so anyone reading can understand my thought process, and the withdrawstep() function has not been added yet):

```
print "Welcome to the Piggy Bank!"

def depositstep(): 
    deposit = raw_input("What would you like to deposit? (P for pennies, N for nickels, D for dimes, Q for quarters): ").upper() 

    if deposit == 'P':
        pennies_previous = 
        pennies_instance = raw_input("How many pennies would you like to deposit?: ")
        pennies_total = int(pennies_instance) + pennies_previous 
        print "There are %s pennies in your bank"% (pennies_total)
        return execute()

    elif deposit == 'N':
        N = raw_input("How many nickels would you like to deposit?: ")
        return 

    elif deposit == 'D':
        D = raw_input("How many dimes would you like to deposit?: ")
        return 

    elif deposit == 'Q':
        Q = raw_input("How many quarters would you like to deposit?: ")
        return 

    else:
        return "Sorry. Please Type P for pennies, N for nickels, D for dimes, or Q for quarters."

def execute():
    exc = raw_input("Would you like to deposit or withdraw money? (D for deposit, W for withdraw): ").upper()

    if exc == 'D' or exc == 'DEPOSIT':
        return depositstep()                        

    elif exc == 'W' or exc == 'WITHDRAW':
        return withdrawstep()

    else:
        return "Sorry. Please type D for deposit or W for withdrawal." 

print execute()
```

Comment: Well... you have to save your information somewhere, like a file or a database. Currently, it will reset every time you run it, since you're not saving the state anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your total amount of pennies in the original variable.
pennies_previous= int(pennies_instance) + pennies_previous then the amount of pennies will be stored there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make the bank continue to store the value of the bank for each session, then you are going to want to save the bank's value to a file.  You could do it like this:
1. First, make a file with a name like bankvalue.txt.
2. Then, add these lines before every return:

```
value = open(bankvalue.txt, 'w') # that opens your bankvalue.txt file in write mode
value.write('\n'pennies_previous) #You should use the answer above for the pennies_previous
value.close() #saves the file
```

3.Then, in order to tell a person their balance you would use the readline() function

I hope that was what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

I would use a python dictionary instead of variables:

do so as:

```
bank = {'pennies':0, 'nickles':1, 'dimes':0, 'quarter':0}
```

to increase either of those you do

```
bank['pennies'] += int(pennies_instance) # not need the pennies_previous
```

Then you need to write that to a file which you could do:

```
f = open('filename','w') 
f.write(bank.items())
f.close
```

But that don't preserve the python structure.  But you can use [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), which is simple as:

```
import json

f = open('filename','wb')
json.dump(bank,f)
f.close()
```

And at the start of the script you need to fetch the data from the file, you do this with

```
f = open('bank.dat','rb')
bank = json.load(f)
```

It would look like this:

```
import json

f = open('bank.dat','rb')
bank = json.load(f)
f.close()

## you code goes here.

f = open('bank.dat','wb')
json.dump(bank,f)
f.close()
```

There are some other problems in your code that should be addressed too.

1) In the 'else' part of your code, if the user inputs the wrong letter it terminates, instead it should call the function again.

2) You don't need to return a string and print it in the 'print execute()', you could just print it in place and don't return anything.